# getting list of hotel names using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8em81.png)

I'm trying to get the list of hotels, but the i'm getting number of elements present in the list after first for loop as zero so element is not getting printed

url: https://www.hotelscombined.in/

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There's no exact List to handle it.

Use this locator to get all elements as results:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'Base-Results-HorizonResult')]
```

Now, you can iterate trough WebElements list and perform your actions, or if you want to access one based on index, you can use:

```
(//div[contains(@class, 'Base-Results-HorizonResult')])[your-index-starting-from-1]
```